# Mapbox JS - Update map programatically when parent state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, gatsby, mapbox-gl-js

## Gatsby project - trying to highlight a Mapbox route when state with desired route is updated.

### Current implementation:

- Load map
- Update parent list state with updateList function
- Parent forwards updated list to other component to display a list of routes
- One of the listItems gets hover
- activeItem state gets updated
- activeItem makes a popup appear on the current map >>>> not working

Since the mapbox map only seems to load properly in the useEffect hook, I don't see any other way of making the popup appear based on the parent's activeItem. If there are alternatives, please let me know!

### Approaches I have tried:

- Extract map from the useEffect hook and instantiate it in a normal const -> “Error: Invalid type: ‘container’ must be a String or HTMLElement.”
- Creating a state for the map with the useState hook -> Map is undefined for all the map related functions e.g. map.on("load", ....)

### Current code:

```
const EmbeddedMap = ({ updateList, activeItem }) => {
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null)
  const [list, setList] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {    
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainerRef.current,
      accessToken: process.env.GATSBY_MAPBOX_TOKEN,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/...",
      center: [-90.836, 51.134],
      zoom: 6,
    })

    const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()

    const getUniqueFeatures = (array, comparatorProperty) =>
      array.filter(
        (v, i, a) =>
          a.findIndex(
            t =>
              t.properties[comparatorProperty] ===
              v.properties[comparatorProperty]
          ) === i
      )

    const updateMap = map => {
      const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ["data"] })
      if (features) {
        const uniqueFeatures = getUniqueFeatures(features, "post_id")
        setList(uniqueFeatures)
      }
    }

    map.on("load", () => {
      updateMap(map)

      map.on("movestart", () => {
        map.setFilter("data", ["has", "title"])
      })

      map.on("moveend", () => {
        updateMap(map)
      })

      map.on("mousemove", "data", e => {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer"
        const feature = e.features[0]
        setPopup(map, popup, feature)
      })

      map.on("mouseleave", "data", () => {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = ""
      })

      map.on("click", "data", e => {
        const feature = e.features[0]
        map.flyTo({
          center: feature.geometry.coordinates[0],
        })
        setPopup(map, popup, feature)
      })
    })

    return () => map.remove()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <EmbeddedMapStyled ref={mapContainerRef} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my approach to a ref solved the problem:

```
const map = useRef(null)
map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainerRef.current,
      accessToken: process.env.GATSBY_MAPBOX_TOKEN,
      style: "mapbox://styles/data",
      center: [-114.836, 51.134],
      zoom: 6,
    })
```

Then I can easily reuse the map by using for example:

```
map.current.flyTo({
      center: activeItem.startPoint,
    })
```